# Can server side redirects make a domain unusable forever?

Tags: php, .htaccess, loops, redirect

There's an element of drama to this question.

A friend built and hosted my organization's website. Then the relationship turned sour with the friend. Anticipating he might try to mess with the website, I changed the password on our GoDaddy account, thinking I could simply point the domain to a new server, removing his ability to mess with our site.

Before I pointed the domain at a new server, the website began showing a redirect loop.

It occurs to me that, if this former friend created a server side redirect loop for my organization's domain, even if I point the domain at a new server, the redirect loop might still exist, rendering my domain useless.

I'm not a developer. Is my logic correct here? If it is, is there anyway to fix this and get my domain back?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Domains have absolutely nothing to do with HTTP, which is where your redirect loop is occurring.  If the requests don't make it to that server, then there is no redirect loop.

The only permanent damage is to your reputation and SEO.  I should also point out that "permanent" redirects (typically done with a 301 status code) *can* be cached indefinitely, but in practice are not.